# C# and VBScript Interoperablity

Tags: c#, vbscript, interop, com-interop

I am attempting to create a C# dll that my vbscript can interact with. However, I am getting an error when I try to instantiate the object: "Server could not be found"

Here is my C# Code:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly:System.CLSCompliant(true)]
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly:Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa3")]


namespace InteropTesting
{
    [Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa3")]
    public class TestReply
    {
        public string salutation;
        public string name;
        public string time;
    }

    [Guid("a22f4018-8f32-4c02-a748-6701fb617aa3")]
    public class TestObj
    {
        public TestObj() { }

        public TestReply SayHello(string addressee)
        {
            return SayHello(addressee, "hello");
        }

        public TestReply SayHello(string addressee, string greeting)
        {
            string x = String.Format("{0}, {1}!", greeting, addressee);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);

            TestReply r = new TestReply
            {
                salutation = greeting,
                name = addressee,
                time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("u")
            };
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my vbscript:

```
Sub Main
    Dim obj
    Dim reply
    Set obj = CreateObject("InteropTesting.TestObj")
    Set reply = obj.SayHello("Evgeny")
    Debug.Print "Reply at: " & reply.Time
    Set reply = obj.SayHello_2("Evgeny", "wassup")
    Debug.Print "Reply at: " & reply.Time
End Sub
```

I created the SNK using the Visual Studio "Signing" property and then ran the following command from a Visual Studio Command prompt:

> csc.exe /t:library /debug+ /keyfile:InteropTesting.snk/out:InteropTesting. dll Program.cs

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: At the very least you need to use different GUIDs for the assembly and both classes.  Are you [registering the assembly with COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @DStanley that is what I had forgotten to do! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DStanley If I want to run a form in my SayHello function, does that form need to also GUIDs? And, does the file's build action need to be "Content"

Comment: I'm not sure you can create a form from a COM component - you can try it and post another question if/when you get stuck.

Comment: Will post a new question. Thanks

Comment: @DStanley: Could you post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a COM component it needs to be [registered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  That way the system knows where to find the code for a particular component,

In addition, you need to use different GUIDs for the assembly, each interface, and each class.  GUIDs are used to *uniquely* COM classes, interfaces, and type libraries (roughly the COM equivalents of .NET assemblies).  And don't create GUIDs by hand by just changing one "digit".  Visual Studio includes a [GUID Generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241442%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the "Tools" menu that will generate a unique GUID for you.